# Long path break apart fills gaps unnecessarily in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, path

I have a long SVG path that I want to split/ break-apart. both options fills white gaps between nodes unnecessarily. please I want to keep white spaces as is before and after splitting the path.

I am using Inkscape

I used both **Path > Split Path** & **Path > Break-apart**, but they insert black nodes at white gaps as in the figure. I do not want them.

[image]

Comment: @s.ouchene Oh, sorry. Your comment wasn't there yet when I started writing my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Break Apart' operation also separates sub-paths that define holes in shapes, effectively filling them in.

The 'Path → Split Path' operation added in more recent versions of Inkscape (1.2+) does the same as 'Break Apart' but preserves holes in paths.

Demo from the [official release notes](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Release_notes/1.2#Path_Operations):

[image: Break Apart vs Split Path animation]

If you already have paths broken apart and for some reason can't undo the operation, then select both the outer shape and the holes and use 'Path → Combine' to re-add the holes to the shapes.

Comment: I'll update my inkscape now, and give it another try

Comment: Issue solved by Updating to Inkscape 1.3.0

Comment: @Xrott - what a useful new feature!!